# Unable to load image using variable name in pygame

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I've been working on a simple map editor tool for a game project in pygame. Right now I'm trying to have the program load all the images from a specific folder when it launches. For each image I create a file in a list, and make that into a custom class object. It is assigned a *.fileImage* value when I add it as a class object.

The error: 
 `Couldn't open E:\Pygame Engine Test\Assets\\Blocks\coldstoneWideBrick.png`

I only don't understand this error because I've tried debugging the problem for a while now and it makes no sense.

When I load in the image I do this:

```
class editorBlocks:
    def __init__(self, Image, Name, Type):
        self.editName = Name
        self.fileImage = pygame.image.load(blockDir + Image).convert()
        self.obType = Type
```

If I have the program enter "coldstoneWideBrick.png" as the Image value for the class, it returns the above error. I've tried printing *Image* when I input it and get it "coldstoneWideBrick.png". However, if I replace the line that loads the image with this:

```
self.fileImage = pygame.image.load(blockDir + "coldstoneWideBrick.png").convert()
```

It loads the image without error. Why is it that it only has difficulty when I have it use the *Image* input, even though the input has an identical value?

Comment: I don't see a problem in this code and your debugging steps look complete to me. I was able to run it (with minor changes). I suggest that you take a look at how you assign a value to Image (when you call editorBlocks) and if you don't see a problem, post that code also.

Answer (score 0):

After some further review of the problem, I noticed that when i printed in the value there was a blank line after it every time.
I was able to fix it by changing how I loaded in the image value (it was loaded from a file before put into a class.) Sorry for making such a simple mistake and thanks for your time!